# How to render input fields required based on the selection of a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

My intent is to make input and second select fields all required if the value of first select was selected.

Select:

```xml
<select name="AMC_metavalue_tipologia_evento" id="AMC_metavalue_tipologia_evento">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Ingresso Singolo?</option>
    <option value="8" '.selected( $AMC_metakey_tipologia_evento, '8', false ) . '>Orario Custom</option>
    <option value="0" '.selected( $AMC_metakey_tipologia_evento, '0', false ) . '>Annulla orario Custom</option>
</select>
```

Input:

```xml
<input type="text" name="AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_uomo" value="'.esc_attr( $AMC_metakey_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_uomo ).'"/>
<input type="text" name="AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_donna" value="'.esc_attr( $AMC_metakey_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_donna ).'"/>
```

second select:

```xml
<select name="AMC_metavalue_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom" id="AMC_metavalue_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Imposta Cosa ha Uomo</option>
    <option value="Solo Ingresso" '.selected( $AMC_metakey_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom, 'Solo Ingresso', false ) . '>Solo Ingresso</option>
    <option value="Ingresso + 1 Cocktail in omaggio" '.selected( $AMC_metakey_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom, 'Ingresso + 1 Cocktail in omaggio', false ) . '>Ingresso + 1 Cocktail in omaggio</option>
    <option value="0" '.selected( $AMC_metakey_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom, '0', false ) . '>Non Previsto</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#AMC_metavalue_tipologia_evento").on('change',function(element){
    
      if(element.value != ""){
        $("#AMC_metavalue_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom").prop('required',true);
        $("[name='AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_uomo']").prop('required',true);
        $("[name='AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_donna']").prop('required',true);
      }else{
         $("#AMC_metavalue_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom").prop('required',false);
         $("[name='AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_uomo']").prop('required',false);
        $("[name='AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_donna']").prop('required',false);
      }
  });
  
  $("#submitButton").on('click',function(){        
        $.each($("#second").children(),function(index,element){ 
          if($(element).prop('required') == true){
            $(element).addClass("required");
          }else{
            $(element).removeClass("required");       
          }
        })       
  });
  
});
```

```css
.required{
border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div id="first">
<select name="AMC_metavalue_tipologia_evento" id="AMC_metavalue_tipologia_evento">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Ingresso Singolo?</option>
    <option value="8">Orario Custom</option>
    <option value="0">Annulla orario Custom</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="second">
<input type="text" name="AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_uomo" value=""/>        

<input type="text" name="AMC_metavalue_primo_orario_prezzo_pista_donna" value=""/>   

<select name="AMC_metavalue_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom" id="AMC_metavalue_cosa_ha_uomo_primo_orario_custom">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Imposta Cosa ha Uomo</option>
    <option value="Solo Ingresso">Solo Ingresso</option>
    <option value="Ingresso + 1 Cocktail in omaggio">Ingresso + 1 Cocktail in omaggio</option>
    <option value="0" >Non Previsto</option>
</select>
</div>
<button id="submitButton">submit</button>
</body>
<html>
```